# I'm having problems with applying padding to my navbar (when expanding it)

Tags: frameworks, height, navbar, padding

I want the navbar always to be of a certain height, but when applying certain padding, when expanding the menu the whole navbar expands, and the initial not expanded navbar 'loses' part of its height, and also you see that padding to the sides. It's a bit tricky for me to explain but you'll hopefully see what I mean in this example:

```css
#navbarMain {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#6ebebe, #28648c 80%);
    padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar-nav {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav id="navbarMain" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top shadow">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"> <i class="fas fa-book text-light"></i> Navbar Brand</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
      
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Toys</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Store</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

As you can see, when expanded the gradient is being applied to the whole expanded navbar (brand + li) , and I need that gradient to be applied only an always to the initial 'non expanded navbar' (brand section). Is it a way to keep the 'not expanded navbar’ applied properties sort of independent from the expanded menu?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use @media queries to perform this task! Set a break point for your application and define the required backgrounds for them

Answer (score 0):

You may use a media query to solve this problem

[check this link may solve your issue](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: I don't see how media query could solve this, can you illustrate me? It doesn't break when resizing, it breaks when expanding the menu...

Comment: Can someone help me out with this?